# Issue with the CSS property float

Tags: html, css, css-float

These are the codes I am using: http://jsfiddle.net/VaKSG/

```
.brs_top_bar{
    width: 900px;
    height: 40px;
    background: rgb(27, 124, 124);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(20, 92, 92);
    color: white;
}
.brs_top_search{
    width: 201px;
    height: 40px;
    background: rgb(22, 105, 105);
    display: inline-block;
}
.brs_top_show_hide{
    height: 40px;
    width: 10px;
    background: rgb(78, 218, 218);
    display: inline-block;
}
.brs_top_pages_info{
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 30px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.brs_top_pages_but{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 28px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 28px;
    width: 28px;
    background: rgb(35, 156, 156);
    border: 1px solid rgb(31, 139, 139);
    display: inline-block;
 }
 .brs_top_pages{
    margin: 5px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
 }
.floating{
    float: right;
    position: relative;
 }
```

---

```
<div class="brs_top_bar">
    <div class="brs_top_search"></div>
    <div class="brs_top_show_hide"></div>
    <div class="brs_top_pages floating">
        <div class="brs_top_pages_info">1 - 10 of 300</div>
        <a href="" title="" class="brs_top_pages_but"><</a><a href="" class="brs_top_pages_but" title="">></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

It runs ok in the link but in my local environment, the floated element goes under the other elements within the same container as shown in the picture:

[image]

I tried almost everything to get it right but did not work.I am using Chrome.

Comment: works pretty fine on both ff and chrome. You can use `inspect element` utility of Chrome to diagnose what's wrong with the elements' layout. It seems like that some other elements break the layout, not the lines you pasted here and jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for css. Just add `float:left` in both class.

```
.brs_top_search{
    width: 201px;
    height: 40px;
    background: rgb(22, 105, 105);
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
.brs_top_show_hide{
    height: 40px;
    width: 10px;
    background: rgb(78, 218, 218);
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```